# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, maven, cxf, wicket

I have a weird problem, I am not able to run my project suddenly. The same project works on another computer as expected but when I run it on my office computer it gives me a classNotFoundException for cxf.

I build my project using maven and the project has been created in wicket.

Root cause:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:392)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
```

When I try to explicitly add cxf dependencies in pom.xml file it starts giving me other weird exceptions, like other classes could not resolved.

Could any one help me with the most possible reason for such a behavior.

Pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>application-name</artifactId>
<groupId>de.application-name</groupId>
<name>nickname</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <configuration>
                <reload>manual</reload>
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>src/main/webapp</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Integration Tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>wiquery-maven-repo</id>
        <name>WiQuery repository</name>
        <url>https://wiquery.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.wicked-charts</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicked-charts-wicket6</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson for JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- EhCache -->


    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EXTERNAL FACEBOOK DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-annotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.6.0</wicket.version>
    <springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springframework.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</springframework.security.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-annotations.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate-annotations.version>
    <jackson.version>2.1.4</jackson.version>
    <base.path>${basedir}</base.path>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

</properties>
```

Comment: Where do you run it on: some (application) server (tomcat/jboss etc..)? Could be the difference is there in the jars _embedded_ in the server. Classpaths / `/ext` directories et cetera. Also: Perhaps it would help to show your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I run it using jetty, by starting a apache server via xampp

Comment: share the pom file - are you sure you have all the dependencies?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the pom file, and yes I am pretty sure that I have all the dependencies as the project with the same pom file and configuration ruins perfectly well in the old system I used, the problem started on my new machine.

Answer (score -1):

The maven repository (.m) has no dependencies repository where if you compile your project. 
Try copying the repository if it works on the machine where you have problems.

**Repository path**: dir \ user \ .m2

Please set up now where you should read the maven repository (settings.xml).